# Representar clave unica en el modelo ER si no es clave primaria

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Tengo una tabla citas que tiene una FechahoraCita un id un licencia de medico y un nº de SS de paciente.
La clave primaria es la ID luego tengo 2 claves unicas compuestas de la fecha y la licencia y el paciente y l la fecha. De esta manera un paciente no puede tener mas de una cita a la misma hora y un medico no puede tener mas de una cita a la misma hora. Mi problema esta en que tengo que realizar el modelo ER y no se como representar las claves unicas que no son primarais. Este es mi modelo ER que que realizado sin claves unicas
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es que, eso que comentas, pertenece al modelo relacional, no al conceptual, ¿no?

Comment: Quizas no se represente ya no lo se seguro

Comment: Las claves no primarias no van al modelo er.. van al diccionario de datos.